# Fake notification of burning files

Tags: windows-vista, burning

There are no files in my dvd drive still it gives me fake notification of there are file waiting to be burned.

[image]

And when I click on the notification it shows me this window.

[image]

I have LG DVD writer and I am using Windows Vista Home Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you drag and drop some files into a CD drive in Explorer, they aren't burned immediately -- instead Windows saves a copy in a `CD Burning` cache folder hidden deep inside Local Application Data. (This is because [direct writing requires special software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_writing).)

In Windows Vista, the cache folder is`*`:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\CD Burning
```

*`%USERPROFILE%` will be autoreplaced with your user profile (`C:\Users\Searock`).*

If there are any files in that folder, remove them.

---

*`*` Should be. I haven't upgraded from XP yet, so I had to google out the path.*

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer, that's  really nice of you. I couldn't find any CD Burning folder, but there is a folder called Burn. I deleted the files inside it and it did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling hidden files. I suspect that there may be some in there, but they are just not visible.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out!